# SQLite strange value returned by sqlite3_column_text

Tags: c++, sqlite

I've a c++ project where is installed sqlite.

When the application starts it will creates the database using this code:

```
    // Open connection with database
if (SQLITE_OK != sqlite3_open_v2("Test.db", &db, SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE | SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE, nullptr)) {
    return false;
}

// Delete old tables if exists
char * error;

if (SQLITE_OK != sqlite3_exec(db, "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Tests;", nullptr, nullptr, &error)) {
    return false;
}

// Recreate all tables
if (SQLITE_OK != sqlite3_exec(db, "CREATE TABLE Tests(testID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC, name TEXT NOT NULL);", nullptr, nullptr, &error)) {
    return false;
}

// Test only
if (SQLITE_OK != sqlite3_exec(db, "INSERT INTO Tests(testID, name VALUES (1, 'Andrea');", nullptr, nullptr, &error)) {
    return false;
}
```

When I execute this code:

```
sqlite3_stmt *query = nullptr;
if (SQLITE_OK != sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "SELECT testID, name FROM Tests;", -1, &query, nullptr)) {

}

unsigned char const * t = nullptr;
if (SQLITE_ROW == sqlite3_step(query)) {
    t = sqlite3_column_text(query, 1);
    sqlite3_finalize(query);
}

printf( (char*)t );
```

I'm expecting "Andrea" but this code print: 
 - PÝòea 
 - ð¶òea
 - ð§òea

Different result each time.

Comment: Try to print it out before you finalize

Comment: Thanks you, now works!

Comment: You have another bug. When there are no more rows in the result `sqlite3_step()` will return SQLITE_DONE. In that case you also need to call `sqlite3_finalize()`. So `sqlite3_finalize()` should go after `if (SQLITE_ROW == sqlite3_step(query))` block, not inside of it.

Answer (score 2):

According to the `sqlite3_column_text` [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html), pointer `t` becomes invalid after `sqlite3_finalize`:

> In other words, you should call **sqlite3_column_text()**, sqlite3_column_blob(), or sqlite3_column_text16() first to force the result into the desired format, then invoke sqlite3_column_bytes() or sqlite3_column_bytes16() to find the size of the result.
>
> The pointers returned are valid until a type conversion occurs as described above, or until sqlite3_step() or sqlite3_reset() or **sqlite3_finalize()** is called.

As suggested by @tkausl, to fix the problem you should print the data or copy it somewhere for further use before `sqlite3_finalize` called.